# C# Send request out over a network and wait for a response, from anything?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I'm potentially looking to send out a packet, or some kind of request across a network but not to anything specific. A machine or possible multiple would have a piece of software installed listening for a this specific packet or request and respond. The mainframe server would then know it has x amount of servers to share out work too.

Can i use some form of UDP broadcasting or TCP Packets to achieve this kind of thing? I would be using C# .NET to do this.

The end result of this issue would be to have a main server that has tasks to accomplish but likes to share the work out across a number of machine if any of available, but it would never know anything about them. It would send out the request saying "i need some work done" a machine would respond with like "Im free" + the IP Address then the main machine would be able to use TCP connection to deliver work (i can easily achieve this part). I just need to make the initial blind request across a network.

I hope that makes sense, if i have to figure out another way so the main machine knows about all its workers then i will but i would prefer not too.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do multicasting, which is well accomplished with UDP instead of TCP.

I found an article describing how you'd do such a thing.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this code - based on `TcpClient` class

```
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("...",8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str=Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using [ZeroConf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) (aka [Apple Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/), Apple has a Bonjour SDK for Windows). Part of ZeroConf/Bonjour is **service discovery**. The RFCs for which are:

- [RFC 2608, Service Location Protocol, Version 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2608)
- [RFC 3224, Vendor Extensions for Service Location Protocol, Version 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3224)

Both of these RFCs are IETF Proposed Standards.

Here's the Wikipedia article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking

Also, the O'Reilly book, [*Zero Configuration Networking: The Definitive Guide*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101008.do), by Daniel Steinberg and Stewart Cheshire, which collects most of the pertinent information in one place.

[image: book cover]